# Simple differential amplifier with active load for ADC comparator

Tags: adc

I'm wondering, why can't a simple differential amplifier with active load followed by 2 inverters (to boost to VDD and GND logic level signals) be used as a comparator in SAR ADCs? Like this

[image: c]

What's the need for latching and all this positive feedback stuff if the sampled input of the ADC remains at the input to the diff amp for a while, why use positive feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there is a bit of positive feedback, to prevent oscillation that will trash the power rails, and cause many comparators (those not well overdriven into the rails) to
also oscillate.

If the Rnoise is 10,000 ohms (a 12 nanovolt/rtHz noise density) with 10GHz noise bandwidth, the noise of that comparator will be

12nV * sqrt(10GHz)

or

1.2e-8 * 10^+5  == 1.2e-3 = 1.2 milliVolts rms

=================================

how to oscillate? there is feedback using the common VDD rail.

phaseshift and voltage gain ---- oscillate

Comment: Why would oscillation occur in the circuit above? There's no feedback?